# Post Data to PHP script from Android app

Tags: java, php, android, httpclient

I am trying to post data to a PHP script from an Android phone app. This is the code I am using.

```
public class Upload extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText joke;
Button upload;
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upload);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bUpload:
        uploadJoke();
        break;
    }

}
private void uploadJoke() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxx/telejoke.php");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("joke", joke.getText().toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        alertDialog.setTitle("Client Protocol Exception");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        alertDialog.setTitle("IOException");
    }
}
```

}

However, when I try to run it on my android phone, it just crashes with unexpected error. Help with this is appreciated.

Comment: Hello moesef, plz post your error log, so, I can suggest the changes, thx

Comment: You are running network operation in Main Thread, I suggest you to move your network operation in new thread or AsyncTask,

Comment: The errors have something to do with AlertDialog. When I move AlertDialog inside of the uploadJoke method, it takes out the errors... but I still dont think the data is being posted to my PHP script.

Comment: Actually, the AlertDialog was the error that was preventing this from working. Thx for the help @KPBird Should have looked at the error log first thing.

Answer (score 0):

Moving `AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();` within the `UploadJoke` method fixes this issue.